# why is idsntp giving results always current local time via all hosts?

Tags: delphi, indy, ntp

why is idsntp giving results always current local time via all hosts?
I will use current utc/gmt time but, all results are current local time.
there isn't any problem for iddaytime via 'time.nist.gov' host option.
how i get current utc/gmt time with idsntp via 'pool.ntp.org' host or
another ntp server hosts in delphi xe6?

Comment: Its not recommended to synchronize time over WAN using SNTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok my solution:

```
uses
  DateUtils;

var
  GMTTime: TDateTime;
Begin
  GMTTime := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(IdSNTP1.DateTime);
End;
```